# Django Rest Framework Filtering does not response 'No Data Found' when no data found

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a very simple *DRF ListApiView* which is using **filters.SearchFilter** as **filter_backend**.

But the problem is it is returning an empty list if no data is found on the queryset.

My Code:

***serializers.py***

```py
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand_name = serializers.CharField(source='brand')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Phone
        fields = '__all__'
```

***views.py***

```py
class PhoneApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    serializer_class = serializers.PhoneSerializer
    queryset = models.Phone.objects.all()
    search_fields = ['model_name', 'jan_code']
```

***Result for a successful search***

```json
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "brand_name": "Oppo",
        "model_name": "Oppo Reno 5",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/phone/reno-5-black-2.jpg",
        "colors": "Red, Blue",
        "jan_code": "785621716768184",
        "brand": 6
    }
]
```

***Expected Result if nothing found*** (Currently returning an empty list `[]`)

```json
    {
        "response": 'No Data Found'
    }
```

Now, How do I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to start with the filter_queryset() method and work your way to the get() method.

```
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
            queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
        return queryset

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Phone.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):
        filtered_qs = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        
        serializer = PhoneSerializer(filtered_qs, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        if not filtered_qs.exists():
            return Response({'response': 'No Data Found'})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: yes got an error `The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.` when no data found

Comment: I have edited my post above. The response is now returned in the get method instead of the filter_queryset() method.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but this time correct search returns some error.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: `validate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raise_exception'` This is the error message I am getting.

Comment: And if I remove that Line then ```Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `brand_name` on serializer `PhoneSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'brand'.``` This is the error I am getting for correct search

Comment: The correct method is ```is_valid()``` instead of ```validate()```. Sorry.

Comment: ```Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.``` What do I pass as data=?

Comment: Hmm, pass the data=request.data in the Serializer() method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240442/discussion-between-yusuf-ertas-and-nahidujjaman-hridoy).